# How to use R's sprintf to create fixed width strings with fill whitespace at the END?

Tags: r, formatting, output, printf

I have vector of strings and want to create a fixed with string out of that. Shorter strings should be filled up with white spaces. E.g.:

```
c("fjdlksa01dada","rau","sjklf")
sprintf("%8s")
# returns
[1] "fjdlksa01dada" "     rau"      "   sjklf"
```

But how can I get the additional whitespace at the END of the string?

Note that I heard of write.fwf from the `gdata` package which is really nice but doesn't help much in this case, because I need to write a very specific non-standard format for an outdated old program.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add a minus in front of the 8 to get a left-aligned padded string

Comment: True, but not what the OP asked for.

Comment: It is not? He writes "But how can I get the additional whitespace at the END of the string?" or do i have something confused?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The OP did ask for the whitespace at the end, so I think this fits that

Comment: This IS exactly what I want. Thanks for helping out a C newbie. I can only +acc one answer, but +1`d both. Thanks for the help and additional info.

Comment: You are correct--I misread from his example. He got left-padding, and I thought he wanted left-padding.  My bad, sorry.  It was a poorly worded question.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel _"He got left-padding, and I thought he wanted left-padding."_  Riiiighhhttt.... ;-)

Answer (score 12):

That is almost more of a standard "C" rather than R question as it pertains to `printf` format strings. You can even test this on a command-prompt:

```
edd@max:~$ printf "[% 8s]\n" foo
[     foo]
edd@max:~$ printf "[%-8s]\n" foo
[foo     ]
edd@max:~$
```

and in R it works the same for padding left:

```
R> vec <- c("fjdlksa01dada","rau","sjklf")
R> sprintf("% 8s", vec)
[1] "fjdlksa01dada" "     rau"      "   sjklf"     
R>
```

and right

```
R> sprintf("%-8s", vec)
[1] "fjdlksa01dada" "rau     "      "sjklf   "     
R>
```

*Edit:* Updated once I understood better what @ran2 actually asked for.

Comment: Is there a direct way to add trailing `0`s instead of whitespaces using `sprintf()`? I am currently wrapping the outcome in `gsub(" ", "0", ...)`, which feels a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The stringr package provides `str_pad`:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("fjdlksa01dada","rau","sjklf")
str_pad(x, width=8, side="right")
```

which yields:

```
[1] "fjdlksa01dada" "rau     "      "sjklf   "
```